# first call to async to await still having error IEnumerable<MyDataType> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, async-await

I got a webapi where the controller is making a call to the business layer and then to the entity framework code to get data.

I was able to fix the error in the EF class by changing the code to

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyDataType>> GetDataAsync()
{
var myTask = Task.Run(()=> MyDbContext.Table1.OrderBy(p => p.Title).ToList());
return await myTask;
}
```

From my controller, I am still getting the same error

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyDataType>>> Get()
{
  var collection = await handler.GetDataAsync();
return collection;
}
```

With .NET Framework 4.6, I usually add the async await to all my methods from Controller to business layer methods and the GetDataAsync call.

With C# 7.0, is it that we don't need the async call in the controller and only in the data layer method? In my code, the controller makes a call to the business layer and then it will call the DbContext method.

How do I fix this bug in the controller?

Thanks

Comment: Your first method there is really nasty. All you need for an EF call is: `return await MyDbContext.Table1.OrderBy(p => p.Title).ToListAsync();`

Comment: As for your second snippet, what does `handler.GetDataAsync` return? Does it return a `Task<>`?

Comment: There is some misunderstanding, the controller will be calling the business layer method and not the DbContext object. It returns a list of records.

Comment: So you haven't shown the middle layer code? You need to show the full code path. And async needs to be all the way throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing and the async await calls are different now with C# 7.0.

In my data layer, I used Task.Run and that fixes my compile error on that class.

At the top, I did the same with Task.Run on the controller method and Task.Run call the business method with async and await.

It is different from the old .net framework code. Hope it helps others.